# When IE launches for debugging in Visual Studio 2010, is there a way to make it go directly to inprivate browsing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer

I seem to have a repeated problem with caching of js files while debugging. Even though I make sure to stop the development server before starting debugging again. I also checked that the files are marked as 'content' and 'copy always'. My hope is that defaulting to inprivate browsing might help.

Is there a way to have it launch directly to inprivate browsing when launched by visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.meidianto.com/2010/08/01/vs2010-tips-14-how-change-the-default-browser-used-in-debugging-asp-net-mvc-2-application/

http://blog.meidianto.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/image1.png

but I basically added -private ahead of the command line args infront of the url